# I have an (name: 'xyzsdk_v1.0.20', ext: 'aar') file and i want to integrate it in my ionic project and also i created one custome plugin

Tags: javascript, python, java, css, reactjs

- I want to call the function from sdk file to my ionic project by using custom plugin.
- All versions:- cordova 10.0.0, ionic 7.0.1, ng version 9.1.13, node 16.20.0, gradle 6.5.1

I tried with the help of plugin. plugin was created successfully but not integrate in my ionic project. also i integrated sdk in ionic but I failed in calling the function from sdk to plugin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.